# Batch file to zip files inside a folder with a specific file type

Tags: batch-file, zip

I need a batch file to zip files inside a folder with a specific file type. The file type is (.asc).

Could anyone help me correct the code I have below?

Thanks.

```
for /r "C:\Test_Results\Report_%Date:~-10,2%_%Date:~-7,2%_%Date:~-4,4%" %%G in (.asc*)do (  
  if /i "%%~nxa"==".asc" (
    pushd "%%a"
    REM zip all files in the backup directory  
    FOR %%A IN (*.asc* *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.rar" "%%A"
    FOR %%A IN (*.asc *.cpi) DO DEL "%%A"
    popd 
  )
)
```

Comment: *WinRAR*  creates a RAR archive if you specify to create a *.rar file and not a ZIP archive. So you need to use `"%%~nA.zip"` or use the switch `-afzip` and let each user think the *.rar file created is a RAR archive although it is in real a ZIP archive.

Comment: Start *WinRAR*, click in menu __Help__ on menu item __Help topics__, select tab __Contents__, open list item *Command line mode*, read first the help page *Command line syntax*, then open from list *Switches* and open help page *Alphabetic switches list*. Build the command line while reading about the switches from top to bottom.

Comment: if by file type you mean file extension, you should not use `.asc*` but `*.asc` to get all files with .asc extension. [`*`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) kind of means "Anything can com at this place, even nothing". So by using `.asc*` you're actually asking for all files named `.asc` or with names starting with `.asc`. `*.asc*` is equivalent with saying files that have `.asc` in their name. There is one thing I don't get though: what are you trying to verify with your `IF` statement??

Comment: Hi, yes my idea was to create a compressed version of each file and delete the original. Can you see anything wrong with the for loop in the code? I can't seem to get it working. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnLatimer see my comment

Comment: check your `for` variables: There is a  `%%G` <-> `%%a` mismatch.

Comment: There is a _space_ missing between `)` and `do` in your first line: `for /r ... %%G in (.asc*) do (`

Answer (score 0):

The code below zips files inside any folder called `Logfile`. This works well but I now need to do something a little different (as mentioned in the first post).

@[J.Baoby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7170434/j-baoby), I have changed the `.asc*` to `*.asc`, but I'm still having issues with zipping the files. I'm actually not sure what the **IF** statement after the **FOR** loop is doing. Is it needed here?

@echo 1. This step zips all files inside any folder with the name `Logfile` under C:\TestReports\Report_today's date.

```
for /d /r "C:\TestReports\Report_%Date:~-10,2%_%Date:~-7,2%_%Date:~-4,4%" %%a in (Logfile*) do (  
    if /i "%%~nxa"=="Logfile" (
        pushd "%%a"
        REM zip all files in the backup directory
        FOR %%A IN (*.blf* *.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A"
        FOR %%A IN (*.blf *.cpi) DO DEL "%%A"
        popd 
    )
)
```

Comment: I understand this is not an answer to this post but I wanted to add this code so you can see what the code did previously